# How to count the frequency of a specific value in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to count the number of times the word "unacc" occurs in the column "evaluation" in this excel data file using pandas. With the below code, I can see that there are 1210 "unacc" occurrences but I want to be able to just print that number instead of printing all the unique values in the column. How would I go about that?

```
import pandas as pd
data_file=pd.read_csv('9car.data.csv')
print(data_file.evaluation.value_counts())
```

Comment: that only prints the number of unique values, I need the number of times a specific value occurs within the attribute

Comment: Yep I misread. See jezraels answer below